# email verification form php

Tags: php, validation, email, webforms

I have a web page registration form which asks for the person's email address plus some other info.
When the page is submitted the programs checks if that email address is already in the database. If it is not the info is added to the database and an email is sent to the registered email address with a link which which is then used to verify the person's email.
If the email is already present in the database the registration is prevented.

How do I deal with a malicious entry if the email entered does not belong to the person entering the form but belongs to another potential registrant?
True a verification email will be sent but it might be ignored since the recipient did not register in my website

Could use some ideas
Thanks

I am not sure how to proceed to prevent a malicious entry

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You've basically already dealt with it. The validation email is the way you stop someone registering with another person's email address, because - unless they've gained unauthorised access to that mailbox - they can't ever verify the account and complete the registration.

The only problem I can think of with your description is what happens if someone tries to register with an email they cannot verify, and then later the legitimate owner comes along and enters that email again.

There are probably a couple of solutions:

1. At registration, if someone tries to register with an existing but unvalidated email,simply re-send the validation mail again as if nothing had happened.

And / or

2. Set an expiry time so that if an account is not verified within a set amount of time, you automatically delete that record from the database.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking along the lines of setting the expiry time. Option 1 is ok except the impostor has not only hijacked email but also entered some phony info as well. The rightful owner of the email would have to edit his personal info.

Comment: I agree I think option 2 is better. Do you also have any mechanism for someone to report a phony signup attempt? E.g. if they receive a verification email they weren't expecting

Comment: I also thought of sending the true owner of the email which gets a "username already taken" an email with a link which sends them to a page which verifies them as well as gives a form to edit the information which the impostor sent.  Regarding option 2 to remove unverified entries after an expiration period, how can this be implemented automatically?

Comment: You can use a cron job to query the database automatically on a schedule, for any unverified entries which are X time less than the current date/time, and delete them